# Не записывать данные в access_log если статус 304

Tags: nginx

У меня такой вопрос, можно ли в nginx, записывать данные в access_log файл, сделав условие, чтобы если статус 304 - не записывать...?

Проблема в чём, много статических файлов которые возвращают 304 статус, то есть берутся с браузера, но логов много капец...

Конф nginx

```
log_format custom '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                                       '"$request" [$status] '
                                       '"$http_user_agent" "$http_referer"  ';
access_log /var/www/nginx_access.log custom;
```

Пробую типо такого

```
if( $status != 304 ){
    access_log /var/www/nginx_access.log custom;
}
```

Но ошибку выбивает при запуска nginx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[access_log путь [формат [buffer=размер] [gzip[=степень]] [flush=время] [if=условие]];](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log)**

```
map $status $loggable {
    304  0;
    default 1;
}

access_log /path/to/access.log combined if=$loggable;
```